# grouping query for grafana 3 bar chart

Tags: postgresql, grafana

So I am new to Grafana and I have having issues how to group my query from my postgres database to display the way I would like in the bar chart.

This is the query I am using to get my data and the results using pgadmin:[image]

Here is the result of the query when pasted into Grafana:
[image]

Now this is the result I would like to achieve with my query:
[image]
I would like the x-axis to group GROUP_A, GROUP_B, GROUP_C and GROUP_D bars together as the years are and have the columns in different colors representing each different device.

This is the code used in the tutorial that I would like to achieve but I am having a problem replicating it:

```
SELECT [Month] as [Month], [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014]
FROM (
SELECT
    DATEPART(Year, ModifiedDate) AS [Year],
    STR(DATEPART(Month, ModifiedDate)) AS [Month]
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail a
)AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
COUNT(Year)
FOR [Year] IN ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])
)AS PivotTable
ORDER BY Month
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved it? I faced similar issue so any solutions would be appreciated :D

Comment: I have not solved it, I have moved on

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe how hard this was to figure out but I think I solved this.

The solution to group the columns by each of your groups (GROUP_A, GROUP_B, GROUP_C, etc.) is a combination of two Transformations: the `Partition by values` transform, then `Join by field` transform.

You would `Partition by values` on the `device_type` field, then `Join by field` on the `group_name` field.

From my (potentially flawed) understanding, `Partition by values` breaks the dataset into "series," one series for every value of the chosen partition field.  These are almost like separate tables (to use a SQL analogy), each table having the rows which match each distinct value of the partition field, i.e. a "table"/series with the rows for GROUP_A, one for GROUP_B, etc.

My test data had the "environment" key (analogous to your `device_type`, with 4 distinct values, so my data got separated into 4 "series":

[image: My test data had the "environment" key, with 4 distinct values, so my data got separated into 4 "series"]

Just like with SQL analogy of tables, if I want to display the data from all of those tables together, I would `JOIN` them together by a column common to all, in your case the `group_name` field.  My analogous `group_name` field was called `metric`:

[image: My analogous group_name field was called metric]

Putting it all together and displayed with the Bar Chart > Orientation = Horizontal : my `http_*`entries are your `group_name` entries, and my "planetscale, rds," etc. tags are your `device_type` entries.

[image: The finished graph]

*These are not actual Planetscale vs RDS numbers, just test data*